# How can we make a project in GitHub visible but no one can open it?

Tags: github

I have a project in GitHub and it is now private( not visible to anyone). I want to make the main folder visible but it still no one can open it or see the content.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. You would have to make a different git repo if you want to keep content private.

If you have files that you want to only keep local and never upload to github consider looking into [.gitignore files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). Keep in mind that you'll still have to create a new repository because gitignores don't hide your previous commits.

[more on .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864292/how-to-hide-files-and-folders-from-github-public)

also, in the event that you're trying to hide API keys or secrets, [more info](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets) but I doubt that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. Actually what I need to keep my folder visible for others but it still shows them  notification that it is private.

Comment: @Maria So you want all the contents of the repository to be visible?

Comment: I need the folder is visible but no one can open it or download it

Comment: say I have a repository called repo1, it has multiple .rar files. I want to leave the repo1 is visible but no one can open it and see its content (.rar files )